# Set values greater than index to be NA, per row

Tags: r

In R, I have a matrix `df`, and vector `invalidAfterIndex`.  For the `i`th row, I would like to set all elements with index greater than `invalidAfterIndex[i]` to be `NA`.  For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5))
> df
            X1         X2         X3          X4
1  2.124042819 -0.2862224  0.1686977  2.14838198
2  0.777763004  0.2949123 -0.4331421 -0.81278586
3 -0.003226624 -0.2326152 -1.5779695 -1.23193913
4  0.165975919 -0.1879981 -0.8214994 -1.40267202
5  1.299195865 -0.9418217 -1.5302512  0.03164781
> invalidAfterIndex <- c(2,3,1,4,1)
```

I would like to have:

```
            X1         X2         X3          X4
1  2.124042819 -0.2862224  NA         NA
2  0.777763004  0.2949123 -0.4331421  NA
3 -0.003226624  NA         NA         NA
4  0.165975919 -0.1879981 -0.8214994 -1.40267202
5  1.299195865  NA         NA         NA
```

How can I do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
is.na(df) <- col(df) > invalidAfterIndex
```

Or, as @digEmAll suggested

```
df[col(df) > invalidAfterIndex] <- NA
```

Comment: Or the slightly less "obscure" `df[col(df) > invalidAfterIndex] <- NA` :D (BTW, thanks for showing me col function, that's one of the function I've probably seen once and immediately forgotten)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `Map`, with which you can pass the column and column position to a function where you can replace elements with index surpassing the invalidAfterIndex with `NA`:

```
df[] <- Map(function(col, index) replace(col, index > invalidAfterIndex, NA), df, seq_along(df))

df
#            X1         X2         X3        X4
#1  2.124042819 -0.2862224         NA        NA
#2  0.777763004  0.2949123 -0.4331421        NA
#3 -0.003226624         NA         NA        NA
#4  0.165975919 -0.1879981 -0.8214994 -1.402672
#5  1.299195865         NA         NA        NA
```